# Can I customize Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I need to open a particular page of a Word document/ PDF on click of a line in Objective-C code while opened in Xcode. This line number will be present in the document. Can I customize so? This might look weird and impossible. Just wanted to know whether it is possible?

Comment: You could possibly do this in an Xcode plugin.

Comment: i have no idea of a xcode plugin? can u pls elaborate how?

Comment: There isn't one. That's what I mean. You could write an Xcode plugin to do this. No idea how though. I've never started looking add Xcode plugins in the past. I'm sure there are tutorials available though.